# Help me to understand the construction "Why + noun / adjective / adverb ?" in which there is not a verb

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, verbs, ellipsis, interrogatives

I came across the sentence "Why + noun phrase?".
This construction is not quite clear to me because it doesn't have a verb.

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/hurry):
**(1a)** *Why the hurry*?
What is the full version of (1a)? (I mean, without ellipsis)

my variant:
**(1b)** *Why is the hurry*?
What is the difference between (1a) and (1b)?

---

my own example, № **(2)**:
A: *Buy some food and beer*.
B: ***Why beer?** I don't drink alcohol*.

Am I using "Why + NP?" correctly here? If not, then why not?
Am I right that "*Why beer*?" means "*Why would I buy some beer*?" ?

---

Can we also use "Why + adjective phrase?" ?

my own example, № **(3)**:
A: *This book is interesting*.
B: ***Why interesting?***

Is (3) correct? If not, then why not?
Am I right that "*Why interesting*?" means "*Why is this book interesting*?" ?

---

Can we also use "Why + adverb phrase?" ?

my own example, № **(4)**:
A: *We need to drive fast*.
B: ***Why fast?***
A: *To be there in time*.

Is (4) correct? If not, then why not?
Am I right that "*Why fast*?" means "*Why do we need to drive fast*?" ?

Comment: I don't think _Why the hurry?_ is an ellipsis; it just uses _why_ to mean _what is the reason for...?_

Comment: You can equally say "What beer?" or "How fast?" or "How interesting?" Whether that counts as ellipsis or not, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples 2–4 are fine. Your 1b simply doesn’t work. A fragment *Why is the X?* begs to be completed: *Why is the X **Y**?* as in *Why is the door open?*

Comment: We can do only a metalinguistic question with "interesting": *Teacher: "Students, I want your essays to be about something interesting!" Johnny Nogoodnik: "Why 'interesting'? I would prefer to bore you to death, you old fart."*